# What is the cost of method calls and return statements in Big O analysis?

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory

I'm just starting out in algorithm analysis and there seems to be come ambiguity when it comes to the cost of method calls and return statements. Some sources count them differently than others so I was hoping for some clarification on this. Take this algorithm I wrote to calculate a max subarray (taken from pseudocode):

```
public static int maxSubFastest(int[] array)
    {
        //index variable t
        int t;
        Integer[] M = new Integer[array.length];
        //initial prefix maximum
        M[0] = 0;

        for (t = 1; t < array.length; t++)
        {
            M[t] = max(0, M[t - 1] + array[t]);
        }
        //maximum found so far
        int m = 0;
        for (t = 1; t < array.length; t++)
        {
            m = max(m, M[t]);
        }
        return m;
    }
```

With the method call to:

```
//method to calculate the max for maxSubFastest
    public static int max(int a, int b)
    {
        return a > b ? a:b;
    }
```

My initial analysis of this algorithm has given me:

T(n) = 8(n - 1) + 9

= 8n - 8 + 9

= 8n + 1 = O(n)

I know the final result will still be O(n), but here, I counted:

```
M[t] = max(0, M[t - 1] + array[t]);
```

As cost 2(n - 1), (n - 1) for assignment and (n - 1) for the method call. I did not count the return statement at the end.

Does this seem like a fairly accurate analysis? Should I have counted the method call as more than cost 1*(n - 1) as well as the return statement at the end?

Comment: Been a while since I've really looked at Big O formally, but you want to get the "big" operations, ones that actually take time.  Usually it all averages out and slow operations and fast ones don't make too much difference.  I'd either count a method call and its return as 1 operation, or not at all.  However modern systems have different speeds of operation based on memory access vs cache, and those differences can be very significant.  If you're making lots of deeply nested calls, the time can be 10 to 100 times what a simple operator takes.

Comment: Also, regarding your question specifically about `max`, most modern JVMs inline methods if they are less than 64 bytes (byte codes) so for a very short method like that one I'd count the overhead as 0: it should be completely inlined and take no extra time at all.

Comment: The method call and return statement themselves are constant factors, which are ignored.

Comment: A few remarks on your code: Instead of commenting what a variable means, name it that way. Your `M` array can be declared `int` instead of `Integer`, improving performance. And local variables like your `M` should begin with a lower-case letter, according to Java conventions.

Comment: *`M` array can be declared `int` instead of `Integer`* `M` is declared an array - needlessly. For contemporary Java/Javas stab at functional coding, see [`max​()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-).

Comment: Thank for you the comments, I know there are some java conventions broken here. I was attempting to follow the pseudocode I was given as closely as possible which is why the code looks the way it does. I will change the Integer array though, that is a good point.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

Calling a method is O(1), executing its body depends on the method, and returning from a method is O(1). So overall it's the method body's Big-O that counts (as long as that isn't the more-or-less impossible O(0)).

**Long explanation**

A method call (as seen from the caller's side) consists of three parts:

- Transferring control and arguments to the called method. As Java doesn't copy instance or array contents before passing them as agruments, that's constant time for every single argument, so for fixed argument lists, that's constant time overall as well. So here we have O(1). If you have complicated expressions to be passed as arguments, count them outside of the method call.
- Executing the method's body (inluding any complicated return expressions). That of course depends on the method. Your `max(a,b)` method has no loop, so it's constant time as well: O(1).
- Returning some value. Once again, Java does no content copying that might result in variable time here, so it's constant time: O(1).

You may ask if transfering control into a no-args method takes the same time as one with 10 arguments. Let's say it's 1 for preparing and executing a method call, and 1 for passing a single argument. Then you get 1 for the first case and 11 for the second. But for Big-O, 11 is the same as 1 (both are constant), so the result is O(1).

Comment: Fantastic explanation, that was exactly what I was looking for. I think the thing that was confusing me was regarding the method call arguments (in this case it contained array indexing) but you cleared that up.